Modify JSON file with PowerShell (WIndows Terminal settings)
I want to edit Windows Terminal settings file (JSON)
I would like to change the default profile to have a defined font.
By default, the Font key and the Face subkey do not exist in profiles.defaults
 "profiles": 
{
    "defaults": {},

i want to add:
"profiles": 
{
    "defaults": 
    {
        "font": 
        {
            "face": "CaskaydiaCove NF"
        }

so im try with code:
$settingsfile = $env:USERPROFILE + "\APPDATA\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json"

$json = Get-Content $settingsfile | ConvertFrom-Json 

$json.profiles.defaults | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Font -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{})

$json.profiles.defaults.Font | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Face -NotePropertyValue ([PSCustomObject]@{})

$json.profiles.defaults.Font.Face = "CaskaydiaCove NF"

$json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $settingsfile

unfortunately I get a monster that doesn't work
"profiles":  {
             "defaults":  {
                              "Font":  "@{Face=CaskaydiaCove NF}"
                          },

do you have any idea?

$json | ConvertTo-Json -depth 9| ...?

You were close, lets break down what you want to do. You want to under property "defaults" to add a new property "font" with name:value pair of "face":"CaskaydiaCove NF" .
You can do this in powershell altogether with one line
$json.profiles.defaults | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Font -Value ([PSCustomObject]@{ Face = "CaskaydiaCove NF" })

However, what you were doing did produce the same result but the problem you were facing is duo to how ConvertTo-Json works, it has a default "depth" if 2 and beyond that it will either give the object type or the value:pair.
so try
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3

And you will see the result you were expecting.
